# Click counting and actions based off count

Tags: javascript, game-mechanics

So I have a button that is the 'mine' for my incremental game. I would like to track the number of times that it is clicked and be able to do two things:

1. Have events happen say every 5 clicks.
2. display the total number of times that is has been clicked.

This is what I have so far:

```
function addstone(){
        //stone = (parseFloat(stone) + 0.1).toFixed(1);
        //stone = stone + 1;
        var count = 0;
        var totalcount = 0;
            $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
                count = count + 1;
                if(count == 5){
                    stone = stone + 1;}
                if(count == 5){
                    count = 0;
                    totalcount = totalcount + 1;}
                }
                document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stone;
    }
```

So what do I need to do from here. My button calls function "mine1Click" which in turn calls the different resource addition functions. so for "mine1Click" I have this:

```
function mine1Click(){ 
    addstone();
    addwood();
    }

function addstone(){
        //stone = (parseFloat(stone) + 0.1).toFixed(1);     TOO LARGE
        //stone = stone + 1;                                TOO MUCH STONE
        var count = 0;
        var totalcount = 0;
            $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
                count = count + 1;
                if(count == 5){
                    stone = stone + 1;}
                if(count == 5){
                    count = 0;
                    totalcount = totalcount + 1;}
                }
                document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stone;
    }   

function addwood(){
    wood = wood + 1;
    document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
}

//function addcopper(){                                     UNIMPLEMENTED

//}
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To do the two things that you need:**

1. Have events happen say every 5 clicks.

   ```
   if(count % 5 == 0){
       // do event
   }
   ```

   `%` is the modulo operator. What this does is it returns the remainder of `count` divided by 5. Hence, every multiple of 5, the condition is fulfilled, and the event is triggered.
2. Display the total number of times that it has been clicked.

   I think what you did is fine. `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = count`

**Putting it together**

You can use a "global" variable

```
    var stoneCount = 0;

    function addStone(){
        stoneCount++;

        if(stoneCount % 5 == 0){
            // do event
        }

        document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stoneCount;
    }
```

or if you dont want to clutter the global namespace:

```
function createStoneCounter(){
    var count = 0;

    return function(){
        count++;

        if(count % 5 == 0){
            // do event
        }

        // display count
    }
}

$("<your selector>").click(createStoneCounter());
```